# Can not initialize jsonResponse in Flutter project

Tags: json, api, flutter, asynchronous, dart

In my project I get my json string which later on i tried to assign to it a jsonResponse variable but I got an error like : The argument type 'Response' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Here's my code:

```
Future getMahalle() async {
    BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: globals.PROD_URL,
      connectTimeout: 5000,
      receiveTimeout: 3000,
    );
    Dio dio = new Dio(options);
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${globals.USER_TOKEN}";
    try {
      var response =
          await dio.get(globals.SELECT_URL); //'api/hizlirapor/selects'
      
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response); //Here is the error line
      MahalleModel mahalleList =
          MahalleModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data['mahalle']));

      return mahalleList;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint("ERRORR!!!!!!!!!!!!! ${e.error.toString()}");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to implement [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) article for example and got stuck. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to decode json returned since you are using dio, dio does that for you.

```
// if it's a single value than try this.
MahalleModel mahalleList = response.data.map<MahalleModel>((mahalle) => MahalleModel.fromJson(mahalle));

// if it's a list than try this.
List<MahalleModel> mahalleList = response.data['mahalle'].map<MahalleModel>((mahalle) => MahalleModel.fromJson(mahalle)).toList();
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion. And now I got a debug console statement: "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments." By the way thanks for the info on dio. I'm newbie on dio.

Comment: what's your frommap?

Comment: please check now..missed "['mahalle']" after response.data...please try now...

Comment: is this working? i had edited my answer...if your way is working than it's okay...else try the edit....

List<MahalleModel> mahalleList = response.data['mahalle'].map<MahalleModel>((mahalle) => MahalleModel.fromJson(mahalle)).toList();

Comment: oh i see your edit on your answer. it works perfectly. thanks for the information you gave was precious.